# "Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process."

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2008

When I try to debug a program in Visual Studio on my local server I get

> Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process.
>   To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator

How can I solve this? I am using Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 5):

in order to ensure that this always runs as an administrator - right click on the visual studio icon and choose properties and then compatibility - then check the privilege level: run this program as an administrator

Answer (score 2):

You have to run Visual studio in administrator mode. When starting studio on Visual Studio icon, click right mouse button and choose "Run as administrator". When load your project.

How to always run VS in administrator mode.
http://mo.notono.us/2010/06/how-to-always-run-visual-studio-as.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your Local Security Policy. In Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Debug program (Policy). Your account or group must be added to this policy.